# Error when loading an image stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

Want to store and retrieve data from database including image, able to store image but unable to display it, due to `isset()` error.

Following are the files I have used.

1. HTML form

   ```
   <html>
       <title>reg</title>
       <style type="text/css">
                   body {
                       background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
                       color: white;
                       padding: 20px;
                       font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;}
                   h4 {
                       background-color: DarkCyan;
                       padding: inherit;}
                   h3 {
                       background-color: #ee3e80;
                       padding: inherit;}
                   p {
                       background-color: white;
                       color: rgb(100,100,90);
                       padding: inherit;}
       </style>

       <form method="POST" action="login_back.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"></br>
       &nbsp<font color="DarkCyan"> Choose a user name:</font> <input type="text" name="username">
       </br></br>
       &nbsp<font color="DarkCyan"> First name:</font> <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
       </br></br>
       &nbsp<font color="DarkCyan">  Last name:</font><input type="text" name="lastname"/>
       </br></br>
       &nbsp<font color="DarkCyan"> File: <input type="file" name="image"></font>
       </br></br>
       <input type="submit" value="Save and Proceed">
       </form>
       </html>
   ```
2. PHP file to store and retrieve data to and from database

   ```
    <?php
       #echo "<body style='background-color:rgb(200,200,200)'>";
       session_start();
       if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_FILES['image']) )
       {
       $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
       $_SESSION['firstname']=$_POST['firstname'];
       $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
       $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
       $image_size=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
       if(!isset($file))
           echo"please select an image";
       else
       {
       $image_name=$_FILES['image']['name']; //grabing image name
       $image_size=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); //getting image size
       }
       echo "</br>";


       #connection to db
       mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db("wordgraphic")or die(mysql_error());



       #checking the available username
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'" ); 
       $ans=mysql_num_rows($query);
       if ($ans > 0) 
       { 
            echo "Username already in use please try another.";

       }

       else if($image_size==FALSE)
       {
       echo"That's not an image.";

       }

       else
       {
       #Insert data into mysql

       #1.Inserting user name & image into db
       $sql="INSERT INTO userdata(username, firstname, lastname, image)VALUES('" . $_SESSION['username'] . "', '" . $_SESSION['firstname'] . "', '$lastname','$image')";
       $result1=mysql_query($sql);

       if($result1)
       {
       echo "</br>";
       echo "Registration successful";
       echo "</br>";

       //displaying image
       $lastid=mysql_insert_id();//get the id of the last record
       echo "uploaded image is :";
       echo "<img src='get.php?id=".$lastid."'>";   >  this command has some mistake

       }#if insertion into db successful
       else 
       {
       echo "Problem in database operation";
       }
       }# else block of unique username n img
       }#end of isset
       ?>
   ```
3. get. php, Additional file to output data, this file has been used in `<img src=get.php?id=$lastid>` and `$_REQUEST` is used in this file. The flow of control is not going through `isset()` creating problem.

   ```
   $image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE id=$mid") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
   $image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
   $image=$image['image'];
   header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
   echo $image;
   }
   else
       {
   echo"error";
        }
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time i posted anything on discussion forum, precisely the question should be,
what could be possibly wrong with this code:

```
$lastid=mysql_insert_id();//get the id of the last record
 echo "<img src='get.php?id=".$lastid."'>";
```

where get.php is :

```
<?php
        #connection to db
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("wordgraphic")or die(mysql_error());
        if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) ) > this block of code is not runninng
        {
        $mid=(int)($_REQUEST['id']);

        $image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE id=$mid") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
        $image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
        $image=$image['image'];
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        echo $image;
        }
        else
            {
        echo"error";
             }
?>
```

Comment: What have you got inside your `$_REQUEST['id']` ? if you print it in `else` like this `var_dump($_REQUEST['id']);`